# How to make rows shuffle?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table with over 10+ rows, and now needed to shuffle all rows randomly and create a new table on it. any ideas ?

Using `select * from table order by random()` seems slow.
raw table is like,and the target column is separated into two parts:

```
+--------+------+--------+------+-----+--------+
| cst_id | name | salary | fund | age | target |
+--------+------+--------+------+-----+--------+
|      1 | a    |    100 | Y    |  33 |      0 |
|      2 | b    |    200 | Y    |  21 |      0 |
|      3 | c    |    300 | Y    |  45 |      0 |
|      4 | d    |    400 | N    |  26 |      0 |
|      5 | e    |    500 | N    |  37 |      0 |
|      6 | f    |    600 | Y    |  56 |      0 |
|      7 | g    |    700 | Y    |  44 |      0 |
|      8 | h    |    800 | N    |  22 |      1 |
|      9 | i    |    900 | N    |  38 |      1 |
|     10 | j    |   1000 | Y    |  61 |      1 |
|     11 | k    |   1100 | N    |  51 |      1 |
|     12 | l    |   1200 | N    |  21 |      1 |
|     13 | m    |   1300 | Y    |  32 |      1 |
|     14 | n    |   1400 | N    |  17 |      1 |
+--------+------+--------+------+-----+--------+

after:
+--------+------+--------+------+-----+--------+
| cst_id | name | salary | fund | age | target |
+--------+------+--------+------+-----+--------+
|      1 | a    |    100 | Y    |  33 |      0 |
|      2 | b    |    200 | Y    |  21 |      0 |
|      8 | h    |    800 | N    |  22 |      1 |
|      9 | i    |    900 | N    |  38 |      1 |
|      3 | c    |    300 | Y    |  45 |      0 |
|     13 | m    |   1300 | Y    |  32 |      1 |
|     14 | n    |   1400 | N    |  17 |      1 |
|      5 | e    |    500 | N    |  37 |      0 |
|      6 | f    |    600 | Y    |  56 |      0 |
|      7 | g    |    700 | Y    |  44 |      0 |
|     10 | j    |   1000 | Y    |  61 |      1 |
|     11 | k    |   1100 | N    |  51 |      1 |
|      4 | d    |    400 | N    |  26 |      0 |
+--------+------+--------+------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Nothing can really be slow with as few rows as 100+ rows.

Comment: Relations have no order. Why do you need shuffled data for creating a new one?

Comment: @JBNizet how about 10+ million rows then？

Comment: @clemens making a model on this dataset and there isa  column to separate the negative and positive samplse，however the rows were arranged orderly ,now I need to shuffle them to fit into

Comment: "*however the rows were arranged orderly*" - there is no such thing as "arranging rows" - rows in a relational database have no "order", so they can't be "arranged" in an order. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? From what you have told use, this sounds like a strange thing to do.

Comment: Queries define a sequence of rows and not tables. You may create a materialized view for storing a specific shuffle, but it would be better to tell us what do you want to achieve and not _how_.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am not good at English express and I have edited the question

Comment: Your question still doesn't make sense (to me at least). Again: rows in a relational database are **NOT** sorted. Any order you see when retrieving the data without using an `order by` is pure coincidence and not guaranteed to be stable. The next time you run the query the order could be a different one.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the table comes from other business department which has been processed by them and sure the form  it's settled even next time

Comment: What is the **real**, actual, underlying problem you are trying to solve with that? You question makes no sense as it stands. Why do you think you need to "shuffle" the rows? What is the problem with the (un-ordered) way they are stored now?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need to fit the data into python and sas model(which is already been built and could not change the codes),the problem is because the models need the target column is shuffle

Comment: Suddenly you want to shuffle _columns_ and not rows?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name shuffle rows only

Answer (score 1):

Following explanation is to create NEW table from existing one with same data as in old one(same schema) with shuffled rows.

Create a new table and import all those rows and records from first table, randomly selected and ordered by the RAND() SQL function:

`CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT * FROM old_table ORDER BY RAND()`

Or if you have created a table identical to the structure of the old one, use INSERT INTO instead:

`INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table ORDER BY RAND()`

That is of course if you want to preserve the primary key identification of each row, which is most likely what you want to do with old tables because of the legacy code and data entity relationships. However, if you want a grand new table with all the shuffled records completely rearranged in order as if it’s for a different application, you can ignore the primary key or ID by not importing the ID field of the old table.

For instance, you got ID, col1 and col2 in the old table as data fields. To create a grand new reordered or shuffled rows version of old table:

`CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT col1, col2 FROM old_table ORDER BY RAND()`

And a new primary key ID will be automatically assigned to each of the rows in the new table.

But in SQL, Relations have no order. Rows in a relational database are not sorted. You may get different order while retrieving.

Comment: Simply because of your last sentence, you should add a new column to the table, containing the randomised value, with which the table can be sorted.  *(And allow that column to be indexed, etc.)*